# Problems moving vertices on local axis

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, normals, axis

When I select only the vertices on one side, they're moving along the normal Z-axis as expected. The vertices are 'sliding' towards the end of the object.
[image: verticles on one side selected]

However, when I'm trying to move the vertices on both sides (since i want to keep both ends the same), something weird happens and the verticles are moving in a different direction.

[image: Verticles on both sides selected]

These are the settings im using:

[image: Settings]

Anything I am doing wrong? Or is this not possible?

Comment: It's not a local axis, it is **Normal** axis

Comment: I don't know your exact circumstances, but on a simple object like that I'd add a simple loop cut in the centre and then bevel it. That will ensure that the outer loops are the same distance from each end of the object.

Comment: double press g.. `G` `G` to slide vertices along same edge and it's gg :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: unfortunately this does not work if you select two objects and 8 vertices on each object....

Comment: Double pressing GG didn't work in this case. In the end I did select both sides separately and just moved it 0.5, since it is indeed a simple model. I was just wondering if i was doing something wrong and if it could be approached differently

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this problem is caused by the very principle of *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins* setting. To make it easy to understand just imagine that you tell blender to scale every loop in local axis individualy, this means that we scale loops of edges independently and not relative to each other as expected.

So you are doing everything right, but we can't scale edges across relative to itself. In order to get the desired result we just need to scale faces nor edges. In this case there will be an individual origin in the middle of each poligon group so their edges could scale relative to it.

Leave the settings as they are, select desired loops of faces and press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>.

[image]